# Output raw html from if statement and combining strings?

Tags: templating, twigextension

I have the following code:

```
<img{{ block.imageWidth|length ? ' width="' ~ block.imageWidth ~ 'px"' }} />
```

If imageWidth is specified as 120, it should output:

```
<img width="120px" />
```

However it is outputting this:

```
<img width=&quot;120px&quot; />
```

I've tried using |raw but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```TWIG
{# set test variable, to make your code work #}
{% set block = {imageWidth: 300} %}

{# the real output #}
<img{{ block.imageWidth|length ? (' width="' ~ block.imageWidth~ 'px"')|raw }} />
```

Works for me

Comment: Ah I was missing the bracket, thank you!